# Неверное отображение combobox C#

Tags: c#, combobox

[image]

При автозаполнении combobox из таблицы с базы данных некорректно отображаются предложенные варианты, как только не пробовал преобразовать, ничего не выходит

```
var group_jobs = (from jb in Data.avto.jobs
                          select jb.name_job);
        foreach (string it in group_jobs)
        {
            
            comboBox1.Items.Add(it);
        }
```

Comment: Проблема либо в шрифте, либо в кодировке данных.

Comment: @aepot чел ты крут, дело было в шрифте, благодарю!